# Why is it the output is NULL when i run this mysql programming?

Tags: mysql

In this code, i'm trying to output some data when the ci_ty is 'QS'. But the out put is NULL. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
delimiter //
create procedure GetFnameAndLname(
                                IN ci_ty VARCHAR(45),
                                OUT p_id INT,
                                OUT f_name VARCHAR(45),
                                OUT l_name VARCHAR(45))

begin
select city into ci_ty 
from fathi.personal;

if ci_ty = 'QS' then
    select idpersonal,fname,lname into p_id,f_name,l_name
    from fathi.personal;

end if;

end

call GetFnameAndLname('QS',@p_id,@f_name,@l_name);
select @p_id,@f_name,@l_name;
```

Comment: Perhaps because you seem to overwrite `ci_ty` by using `select city into ci_ty` there?

Comment: does declare a variable differ from select.. into statements? Sorry for asking this. Bcause i',m new in sql

Comment: why are you using a procedure? what's wrong with a simple query?